# External javascript doesnt work when called using jquery's getScript()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm loading a page using **jQuery**'s `.load()` function. The page I'm loading links to an external **javascript** file. So i try to execute that by calling `getScript()`.

This is the code for loading the page:

```
    <script>
    $j(document).ready(function() {


        $j( "#scriptin" ).load("home.html");

        $j("#index").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); // if desired...
      $j( "#scriptin" ).load("home.html");
  });

        $j("#artists").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); // if desired...

      $j( "#scriptin" ).load( "artists.html" );
      $.getScript("pix.js");


  });

        $j("#concert").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault(); // if desired...
     $j( "#scriptin" ).load( "storminateacup.html" );
     $.getScript("stormload.js");
 });




    });
```

Now when the concert link is clicked, as you can see in the code I load storminateacup.html and after that i call the external script stormload.js
This is stormload.js

```
  $( "#scriptintwo" ).load( "latest.html" );


 });

  $("#artists").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault(); // if desired...
     $( "#scriptintwo" ).load( "artists.html" );

  });


   $("#latest").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault(); // if desired...
     $( "#scriptintwo" ).load( "latest.html" );

  });

  $("#videos").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault(); // if desired...
     $( "#scriptintwo" ).load( "videos.html" );
```

This script doesn't seem to run. When i wrap it around a `$document.ready()` and open the link directly (i.e without `using.load()`) it works perfectly. But when i load it without document.ready nothing happens and when i load it with `document.ready()` only one of the clicks work.

Comment: You can try calling the getScript inside the callback of the load function something like this $j( "#scriptin" ).load( "storminateacup.html",function(){$.getScript("stormload.js");} );

Comment: Nope didnt work. Infact stopped some other scripts that were working when i tried to move them.